# Как работать с локальными нотификациями в iOS, если их больше 64?

Tags: ios, swift, уведомления

В моем приложении есть Table View с ячейками, в которых хранится дата. Пользователь может добавить уведомления, например "уведомить меня за 1 день до даты, в 12:00". Проблема в том, что если ячеек больше 64, то, как я понял сработают не все уведомления. Как лучше поступить в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

Да, если ты поставишь в очередь 65-ое уведомление, то самое старое перезапишется новым. Этот счетчик сбрасывается при заходе в твое приложение, если какие-то уведомления уже отработали. Ты можешь проверять при выходе приложения из background, что уведомлений стало меньше 64 и добавить еще несколько из тех, что установил пользователь, но не удалось разместить из-а лимита в 64 уведомления. Но это сработает только в том случае, если пользователь будет регулярно заходить в приложение.

```
if let count = UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications?.count, count < 64 {
    // добавляем еще нотификаций тут
}
```